# Extract key value pair from cell into new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe where cells in one column typically look like this:

```
[{'source_name': 'mitre-attack', 'external_id': 'T1156', 'url': 'https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1156'}, {'url': 'https://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2017/04/unit42-new-iotlinux-malware-targets-dvrs-forms-botnet/', 'description': 'Claud Xiao, Cong Zheng, Yanhui Jia. (2017, April 6). New IoT/Linux Malware Targets DVRs, Forms Botnet. Retrieved February 19, 2018.', 'source_name': 'amnesia malware'}]
```

How do I extract (in this example) the value 'T1156' of the key 'external_id' into a new column called t_id?

Comment: `df['t_id'] = df.A.apply(lambda x: x[0].get('external_id'))` This can also work.

Comment: @TyngdPunkt - Use `df['t_id'] = df.A.str[0].str.get('external_id')`

Comment: @TyngdPunkt - Or `df['t_id'] = df.A.str.get('external_id')`

Comment: @Mayank Porwal thanks a million you have  solved the problem :)

Comment: @TyngdPunkt - what solution working?

Comment: @jezrael df['t_id'] = df.A.str[0].str.get('external_id')

Comment: @jezrael my mistake sorry, you solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, try like this:

```
df['t_id'] = df['external_id']
```

Comment: No, solution is clearly wrong.

Comment: @jezrael I thought the json was already converted to a df.

Comment: I think issue of OP is convert column to DataFrame.

Comment: This will not work I have no column called external_id. I have a column that contains cells with json and I want to extract the value from the key external_id